# Gmail API Chrome Extension anonymous function error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, anonymous-function, gmail-api

I want to create a Google Chrome extension using the Gmail API following this link:

http://developer.streak.com/2014/10/how-to-use-gmail-api-in-chrome-extension.html

and I downloaded the gist from this link:

https://gist.github.com/omarstreak/7908035c91927abfef59

I am having issues with the oauth2 authentication. When I load the extension, I get the error "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.getAuthToken: OAuth2 request failed:.." And when I view the details of the error, the stack trace returns background.js:2 (anonymous function), pointing at the chrome.identity.getAuthToken function. I have am using a valid client ID.

The code that's being called in my background.js file

```
//oauth2 auth
chrome.identity.getAuthToken(
     {'interactive': true},
    function(){
      //load Google's javascript client libraries
        window.gapi_onload = authorize;
        loadScript('https://apis.google.com/js/client.js');
}
```

);

The code that background.js is being called from in manifest.js

```
  "background": { "scripts": ["base64.js", "background.js"] 
  },
```

How do I get around debugging this error?

Comment: This is, as you can imagine, impossible to diagnose without seeing the code you're using. Having only a link to the code is not OK, and even then we don't know how you modified it.

Comment: Personally I would suggest avoiding loading client.js in a Chrome extension. I don't believe it officially supports it. BTW there is a [full sample](https://github.com/GoogleDeveloperExperts/chrome-extension-google-apis) for authorizing and using the Gmail API in an extension.

Comment: Could you include your full manifest?